# How can I get the physical size of a pixel, in millimeters, at a specific window-zoom level?

Tags: javascript, zooming, screen, pixel

Using javascript.
I know how to get the pixels-per-inch (ppi), but I also need
the physical size of a pixel, especially when zooming out at a low level, like 10%.

Comment: Is this browser?, Unfortunately there is no way of even getting the ppi correctly.  And even if there was, due to browser finger printing it's likely fake.. :(   If your creating a native app, then it might be possible.

Comment: @Keith: Currently my screen has a physical width of 510mm, and a resolution of 1920 px width, 1040 px height. If I'm correct that this corresponds to 100% zoom level, then 1px = 510/1920 mm = 0.265 mm in width. So at e.g. 10% zoom-level, 1 pixel is 0.0265 mm in width. So is the problem solved in this way?

Comment: If you ask your users to supply screen dimension's you could calculate it yes.  But I don't believe you could do it automatically, eg. If my screen was 1000mm wide, I can't get this information from JS.  I believe browsers always assume a PPI of 96 no matter how big the screen.

Comment: ppi = 96 leads immediately to 1px = (25.4/96)mm = 0.265mm at 100% zoom level, agreeing with the computation based on measuring the physical screen.